# Seperate all special characters and words into items in a String List - Regex

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I am attempting to split a string into a list of strings, words being seperate, but surrounding charactors eg.. `"?()“”!"` being seperate also.

String to seperate is `"testing  “testing”  “one two three”  (hi there.) !word"`

Output I would like is

```
[",testing,",testing,",",one,two,three,",(,hi,there,.,),!,word]
```

I been using the following Regex which almost works, but it doesn't seem to pick up the before charactors like (“ etc..

```
RegExp regex = RegExp("(?=[,.?!“”()])|\\s+");


list = context.split(regex).toList();
```

Any suggestions or help from Regex masters out there would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of splitting, you could match either one or more word characters or match any char except a word or whitespace char to get the separate surrounding characters.

```
[,.?!“”()]|[^,.?!“”()\s]+
```

**Explanation**

- `[,.?!“”()]` Match any of the listed
- `|` Or
- `[^,.?!“”()\s]+` Match the opposite except whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IZGseX/1) | [Dart demo](https://tio.run/##TY49DoJAEIVrOMVAw240xF7BysLCRktEs8oImyw/WSZioiYcRC/HRXBFCrv3vUy@N4nQ1PfXUiaQC1kwDnfbushCKDhqTFe3CgLYDoFpL5r6S6drX137Zjx@RId/3tfxxONz21oTanFSuNiRlkUaGjOdM6yNaXT6QqnNr2QuYU3mDMCIxmx8A5YFAjUlUKYRh5Jl0hBq9Dk4TakTl/u5qBjLeRDm0Sz@PlCZWWLjqimeff8B)

*Example code*

```
void main() {
    final _regExp = RegExp(r'[,.?!“”()]|[^,.?!“”()\s]+');
    Iterable<String> matches = _regExp.allMatches("testing  “testing”  “one two three”  (hi there.) !word").map((m)=>m[0]);
    print(matches);
}
```

*Output*

```
(testing, “, testing, ”, “, one, two, three, ”, (, hi, there, ., ), !, word)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, without split how would I convert the output into a List<String>?

Comment: Sorry, if I don't understand, but I don't want to remove the characters I just want them to be a seperate element in the string List, in the same order as the string. I also, don't want to seperate by things like - and ' as they are part of the word makeup

Comment: @Yonkee I have updated the answer. I think you could use this function to get all matches https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/RegExp-class.html

Comment: @Yonkee I have added an example.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain it also, i appreciate the help. Stay safe.

Comment: Might `\w+|[^\s\w]` be enough?

Comment: @CarySwoveland That was my first answer :-) https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61452940/revisions

Comment: I just noticed that there are still spaces attached to the words, is there an option to remove them also? eg..  [this, notthis,this, nothis]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `[this, notthis,this, nothis]` Can yo create a regex101 link with the text for which the matches are not ok?

Answer (score 2):

Matching bits to keep, as Bird #4 has done, seems like the most effective approach. If you are determined to split, however, and your regex engine supports positive lookbehinds and lookaheads, you could split on matches of the following regular expression (some of which are zero-width).

```
\ +|(?<=[^\w ])(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?=[^\w ])|(?<=[^\w ])(?=[^\w ])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/K0AOUu/1/)

At the link I've shown the effect of replacing each match with a comma to make it easier to identify the matches.

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
\ +          # match 1+ spaces (escape not necessary) 
|            # or
(?<=[^\w ])  # following must be preceded by a char other
             # than word char or space
(?=\w)       # preceding must be a word char
|            # or 
(?<=\w)      # following must be preceded by a word char
(?=[^\w ])   # preceding must be followed by a char other
             # than word char or space
|            # or
(?<=[^\w ])  # following must be preceded by a char other
             # than word char or space
(?=[^\w ])   # preceding must be followed by a char other
             # than word char or space
```

All but `\ +` (I've escaped the space so that it can be seen more easily) are zero-width matches, meaning that the string is split between two successive characters (e.g., between `"` and `a` in `..."a...`) and no characters are consumed. `(?<=...)` are *positive lookbehinds*; `(?=...)` are *positive lookaheads*.